# Not receiving notifications from Orion Context-broker after subscription

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm trying examples at "User and Programmer Guide" but I I fail to receive any notification after subscribing for. Updates and queries are working well. The "receptor" script is started this way

```
./accumulator-server.py 1028 /accumulate on
```

and it seems up & runnig

```
verbose mode is on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:1028/
```

Then the subscription seems ok also

```
(curl localhost:1026/NGSI10/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --      header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
        "type": "Room",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "Room1"
    }
],
"attributes": [
    "temperature"
],
"reference": "http://localhost:1028/accumulate",
"duration": "P1M",
"notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL",
            "condValues": [
                "PT10S"
            ]
        }
    ]
    }
   EOF
```

response:

```
{
    "subscribeResponse": {
    "duration": "P1M", 
    "subscriptionId": "535e558d28604367380deb5c"
    }
}
```

Then, an update for Room1

```
curl  -v localhost:1026/NGSI10/updateContext --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @-  <<EOF
> {
>     "contextElements": [
>         {
>             "type": "Room",
>             "isPattern": "false",
>             "id": "Room1",
>             "attributes": [
>             {
>                 "name": "temperature",
>                 "type": "centigrade",
>                 "value": "x"
>             },
>             {
>                 "name": "pressure",
>                 "type": "mmHg",
>                 "value": "x"
>             }
>             ]
>         }
>     ],
>     "updateAction": "UPDATE"
> }
> EOF
* About to connect() to localhost port 1026 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 1026 (#0)
> POST /NGSI10/updateContext HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.2
> Host: localhost:1026
> Content-Type: application/json
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 454
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 513
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Mon, 28 Apr 2014 12:08:38 GMT
< 
{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "Room",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "Room1",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "temperature",
            "type" : "centigrade",
            "value" : ""
          },
          {
            "name" : "pressure",
            "type" : "mmHg",
            "value" : ""
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

But nothing is shown at `accumulator-server`'s output

Any idea about what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: A link to the Orion user manual you mention in the first paragraph will be uselful. I guess you refer to https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide

Answer (score 0):

This is actually due to a "documentation bug" in the User Manual.

Since version 0.10.0, Orion Context Broker is able of sending notifications in both IPv4 and IPv6 and the "localhost" used in the reference element in the subscribeContext operation tends to be resolved to IPv6 by the operating system. Thus, the notifications is sent in IPv6 by default but if the accumulator server is run using

```
./accumulator-server.py 1028 /accumulate on
```

then it only listens to IPv4.

The accumulator-server.py allows to specify the listing address in the command line, thus if you use the following command to specify ::1 (the localhost for IPv6)

```
./accumulator-server.py 1028 /accumulate ::1 on
```

then it should work ok. This is confirmed by the following output:

```
verbose mode is on
* Running on http://[::1]:1028/
* Restarting with reloader
verbose mode is on
```

(Note the ::1 in the "Running on" line above, different from the 0.0.0.0 of the IPv4-only situation)

Thanks to your feedback the User Manual has been fixed and now it uses the right command :)

Comment: As side note, look to the -ipv4 and -ipv6 Orion Context Broker command line options, that can be used to control with IP protocols Orion uses, at https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide#Command_line_options